Python way to change Menu Switch node menu list?
My question is as follows and with the example working code.
I'm trying to change the Menu Switch node lists label in my python code, seems couldn't find a way to do it. The way to do it on the interface is not what I want, because I need to set everything right when start to use in my addon, not let people do it manually every time.

import bpy

def update_geoNode_tree(node_tree):
    
    group_output = node_tree.nodes["Group Output"]
    group_input = node_tree.nodes["Group Input"]
   
    #Socket Menu
    menu_socket = node_tree.interface.new_socket(name = "Menu", in_out='INPUT', socket_type = 'NodeSocketMenu')
    menu_socket.attribute_domain = 'POINT'
    
    #node Menu Switch
    menu_switch = node_tree.nodes.new("GeometryNodeMenuSwitch")
    menu_switch.name = "Menu Switch"
    #####################################
    ### for question to test
    menu_switch.inputs[1].name = "Cylinder"
    #####################################
    
    #node Cylinder
    cylinder = node_tree.nodes.new("GeometryNodeMeshCylinder")
    cylinder.name = "Cylinder"
    cylinder.fill_type = 'NGON'
    #Vertices
    cylinder.inputs[0].default_value = 32
    #Side Segments
    cylinder.inputs[1].default_value = 1
    #Fill Segments
    cylinder.inputs[2].default_value = 1
    #Radius
    cylinder.inputs[3].default_value = 1.0
    #Depth
    cylinder.inputs[4].default_value = 1.0
    
    #node Cube
    cube = node_tree.nodes.new("GeometryNodeMeshCube")
    cube.name = "Cube"
    #Size
    cube.inputs[0].default_value = (1.0, 1.0, 3.0)

    #Set locations
    group_input.location = (-340.9637451171875, 39.62562561035156)
    group_output.location = (326.51617431640625, 65.04036712646484)
    menu_switch.location = (55.20476531982422, 51.1171760559082)
    cylinder.location = (-343.1625671386719, -62.844444274902344)
    cube.location = (-169.79373168945312, -105.80216217041016)
    
    #Set dimensions
    group_input.width, group_input.height = 140.0, 100.0
    group_output.width, group_output.height = 140.0, 100.0
    menu_switch.width, menu_switch.height = 140.0, 100.0
    cylinder.width, cylinder.height = 140.0, 100.0
    cube.width, cube.height = 140.0, 100.0
    
    #initialize node_tree links
    #menu_switch.Output -> group_output.Geometry
    node_tree.links.new(menu_switch.outputs[0], group_output.inputs[0])
    #cylinder.Mesh -> menu_switch.A
    node_tree.links.new(cylinder.outputs[0], menu_switch.inputs[1])
    #cube.Mesh -> menu_switch.B
    node_tree.links.new(cube.outputs[0], menu_switch.inputs[2])
    #group_input.Menu -> menu_switch.Menu
    
    return node_tree

def create_centerpiece():
    
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_circle_add()
    bpy.context.active_object.name = 'testGeoTree'

    bpy.ops.node.new_geometry_nodes_modifier()
    node_tree = bpy.data.node_groups["Geometry Nodes"]
    node_tree.name = "testGeoTree"

    update_geoNode_tree(node_tree)
    #node_tree.nodes['Style Switch'].inputs[0].name = 'Shapes'
    #node_tree.nodes['Style Switch'].inputs[1].name = 'Cylinder'
    #node_tree.nodes['Style Switch'].inputs[2].name = 'Cube'
    #node_tree.interface.items_tree[2].default_value = 'A'


    # make the Geo Nodes modifier the active mode at the end
    bpy.context.active_object.modifiers["GeometryNodes"].is_active = True


def main():
    """
    Python code to generate geo nodes node tree
    """
   
    create_centerpiece()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()



Could you share some code that would be possible to copy/paste and test?

Yes, I just add the code.

In your script you are changing menu_switch.inputs[1].name, but I suspect it gets updated and reset with the value from menu_switch.enum_definition at some point. Try changing the enum_definion in the first place instead. That would be:
menu_switch.enum_definition.enum_items[0].name = "Cylinder"

instead of
menu_switch.inputs[1].name = "Cylinder"

Seems to work fine and update the input name on it's own as well.

Super, this is the way to do it! It's different from other nodes, good to know! Any idea for the 2nd question?

Supposed to be one question. The properties for the items in the interface of the node group are in bpy.context.object.modifiers["GeometryNodes"].node_group.interface.items_tree Use tab key in Python console for autocomplete to explore and also enable Python Tooltips in the Preferences, Interface tab to see hints when hovering over stuff.

If you have multiple questions you should post them as separate questions.

I tried, no effect on the modifiers side and actual geometry tree, but no warnings or errors through the interface.items_tree[].default_value way to set.
Okay, I will post another thread about this question, thank you very much for the help!!!

I think you should edit this one, delete the second question part here and post it as a separate question.

You need to choose the item and set it's name, not default value.

Yep, I just cleaned the question and make it focused. Thx again.

Ohh, I think I didn't make it clear; the name part is working correctly, I need to set up a default value (this is the question about and still couldn't make it work), otherwise it will be empty at the beginning.
